# The best way to create backend admin/ section in Laravel with RESTful controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What is the best way to separate administration logic from front-end in Laravel?

My problem is, that I want to keep the CRUD inside one controller.

For example if I have a Product resource. I want to be able to view product through: `http://my-shop.com/product-category/product/1` but update, create and delete product through: `http://my-shop.com/admin/product/new`

How is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the close vote says, this is broad, but here are some routes to start with:

```
Route::get('{category}/product/{id}', 'ProductsController@show');

Route::get('admin/product/new', 'ProductsController@create')
Route::post('admin/product/new', 'ProductsController@store')
Route::patch('admin/product/{id}/update', 'ProductsController@update')
Route::delete('admin/product/{id}/delete', 'ProductsController@delete')
```

And a controller:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller {

    public function show($category, $id)
    {

    }

    public function create()
    {

    }

    public function store()
    {

    }

    public function store($id)
    {

    }

    public function store($id)
    {

    }

}
```

Of course you could separate those things in two different controllers, since in this case we have admin and non-admin being done by the same controller, but this is entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This might do the trick!

Comment: Strongly advise to separate the controllers and use auth filters.